# SonarQube build step fails with "Self-Signed Certificate in Certificate Chain" in Azure DevOps

Tags: sonarqube, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I am currently setting up a build pipeline in Azure DevOps with a self-hosted agent. Everything is working great so far except the SonarQube build steps.

When executing the Prepare SonarQube on my self-hosted agent it fails with the following error:

```
2018-11-19T14:14:19.1070144Z ##[debug]organization=null
2018-11-19T14:14:19.1087901Z ##[debug]scannerMode=MSBuild
2018-11-19T14:14:19.1093031Z ##[debug]projectKey=online:kiamservices:main
2018-11-19T14:14:19.1095851Z ##[debug]projectName=Online – KIAM Services
2018-11-19T14:14:19.1098962Z ##[debug]projectVersion=1.0
2018-11-19T14:14:19.1104908Z ##[debug][SQ] API GET: '/api/server/version' with query "undefined"
2018-11-19T14:14:19.2819233Z ##[debug][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN"}
2018-11-19T14:14:19.2832616Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2018-11-19T14:14:19.2928009Z ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN"}
2018-11-19T14:14:19.2943259Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN"}
2018-11-19T14:14:19.2946004Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;][SQ] API GET '/api/server/version' failed, error was: {"code":"SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN"}
2018-11-19T14:14:19.3015449Z ##[section]Finishing: Prepare SonarQube
```

If I run the same setup on a microsoft hosted agent it runs just fine.

It is correct that my organization uses it's own Certificate Authority but the certificates are present on the self hosted agent as far as I know.

Is there a way to tell SonarQube to just ignore certificate errors?

I have looked high and low and have sadly not found any information on this error that was even remotely helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, can you show your azure build pipeline, how you configurate your pipeline with self-signed cert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonar uses the Java Keystore for its certificate checks. It doesn't look at windows' keystore at all. You'll likely be able to solve this by importing the correct certificates in the JVM's keystore using the `keytool` utility.

See also:

- https://sylvainleroy.com/2018/07/30/sonarqube-scanner-and-invalid-ssl-certificates/